# How to handle thousands of lights

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm trying to create a night-time city in Blender 3.2. For streetlights I've tried two approaches with geometry nodes:

- Instance lots of balls with an emissive texture.
- Instance actual point lights.

Neither does much in Eevee. Emissive materials don't light surfaces. With more than 128 point lights they get ignored. Cycles is slow in both cases.

I wonder if there is a clever solution? Can I somehow bake this lighting so the roads and buildings get a fast lightmap texture? I want to animate some stuff, but the lights and buildings will be static.

[image: Cycles render of city at night]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a dark city scene setup with emissive materials for the windows and emissive spheres used as street lamps (EEVEE)

[image: Dark]

As you noticed, the emissive lights do not cast light on the surrounding objects - to do this in EEVEE, you will need an *Irradiance Volume*. Scale the Volume to your size requirements and bake the lighting in the render properties tab. You can adjust the cube-map size if you need better resolution (right side)::

[image: Irradiance]

You can also select the Irradiance properties and change the resolution - don't go too high or performance will suffer:

[image: Rad]

Here is the scene after the bake - the lighting will stay the same until you delete the lighting cache or bake again:

[image: Baked]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! I haven't been able to get it working so far, but I'm still pushing the buttons and hoping for the best. (Somehow a different part of the city ends up lit than the one where I put the irradiance volume, and it's not looking great. I'll experiment with a smaller piece to get the hang of it.)